# Connect to Outlook button missing from Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, sharepoint

I am using IE 11 to access a Sharepoint site with a calendar. On IE 10 I could see the option to connect the calendar to Outlook, but on IE 11 this option is missing.

On Windows 7, downgrading to IE 10 would solve the issue, but on Windows 8.1 I haven't found a way to downgrade to IE 10. So is there another way to link a Sharepoint calendar to Outlook?

Comment: What version sharepoint?

Comment: @Raystafarian I can't say as I am not the Sharepoint admin. I was hoping there was a way to do this entirely from Outlook since I have the calendar URL

Comment: Take a look at the security settings in the second response of [this question at microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808799/internet-explorer-11-doesnt-work-well-with-sharepoint-and-infopath-form)

Comment: @Raystafarian Yep, that solved it. Please post an answer so I can give you credit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MS support site](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808799/internet-explorer-11-doesnt-work-well-with-sharepoint-and-infopath-form) this has to do with the security settings in IE11:

> 1.Open Internet Explorer
>
> 2.Click on Tools at the top and select Internet Options
>
> 3.Click the Security Tab
>
> 4.Click Local Intranet
>
> 5.Click Sites
>
> 6.Click Advanced and all of the intranet sites will reappear in the websites box, make sure there is a check box in the Require server
>   verification box
>
> 7.Click Close
>
> 8.Click Ok
>
> 9.Click Ok [done]

Answer (score 3):

I ran to the same problem with Calendar (IE11, MS Office 2010). Setting Local intranet sites didn't help. 
But the MS support site referred by @Raystafarian contains simple and working solution for me:

> Kamil Gozdek on 11/22/2013 at 5:43 AM **Use compatibility view and forms
>   opens normally.**